# Automatic search of most northern/eastern/western/southern polygons in sets of polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-relationship

I have a large set of round polygons, each of them is divided into 4 equal quarters by 2 perpendicular lines with azimuths of 45 and 135 degrees. Is there a way to proceed with an automatic selection of most northern/eastern/western/southern polygon in each of these sets of four?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of what you've got and (if possible) show what your desired outcome is.  What have you tried?  Have you looked at Analysis Proximity toolboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your sectors:

1. Stored as shapefile
2. Have field GRID_ID storing parent circle ID
3. Named SECTORS in mxd table of content

Compute coordinates of centroid inside and populate new field (Short) using this field calculator expression:

```
lr="SECTORS"
tbl=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(lr,("fid","INSIDE_Y","GRID_ID"))
bs=sorted(tbl, key=lambda x: (x[1]),reverse=False)
dPid={}
d={}
for row in bs:
 N=dPid.get(row[2],0);N+=1
 dPid[row[2]]=N
 d[row[0]]=N
def SortGroupOrder(oid):
  return d[oid]
#------------
SortGroupOrder( !FID!)
```

This will populate new field (GROUP_NO) in table below by numbers in range 1..4:

[image]

Records with 1 are your Southern polygons, ones with 4 are your Northern.

Sectors in a picture below labelled by their FID, so expression works no matter physical order of records:

[image]

Re-run expression using INSIDE_X as sorting parameter to find Western and Eastern sectors.

Нажми на Python, Коля!

Comment: Amazing response, thank you very much! I'm only learning Python, your solution would help greatly

Comment: I would suggest using "поднажми" instead, because "нажми" sounds more like "press" or "click" :)

Comment: This can be solved without coding. Sort points by x and y. Points to line, using parent id. Line to vertices and do fid % 4 to populate new field. Records with 0,3 are south and north, etc.